# IP Multicasting: How do I know someone is subscribed?

Tags: c#, c++, boost, multicast

I've been looking into various documentation (.NET WinSock, c++ boost::asio) about multicast. One issue I have is I can't see how you'd know if there is **at least 1 subscriber** to a group. The reason I need it is there's not much point in creating the data if nobody is listening to it. Is there a message sent back from the next hop about the current status of the tree? Is there some kind of event triggered when the first subscriber appears, or when the last leaves?

Comment: no events about subscribers in multicast scenarios...

Comment: @yahia Yes there are. What do you think IGMP is for?

Comment: @EJP no IGMP support in .NET framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to this article on "[How Multicasting Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759719%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)."

In short, your application doesn't need to track multicast subscriptions; the router does that for you.  If you have multicast data to produce, then produce it - the router will take care of whether or not that data gets sent to subscribers.

There are no events that are raised by the router to notify you of subscriptions.  If you want some notifications, you'll have to build that functionality into your own custom protocol implementation, and require that your clients explicitly notify the host.

Comment: So quite simply, if I need to control whether to make the data at all, it would have to be done through another channel?

Answer (score 1):

You can know that if you can issue an IGMP QUERY message, or maybe by listening to IGMP JOIN/LEAVE messages: you will only ever get one of each, unless you are attached to multiple routers. As long as the last IGMP message was a JOIN for your group and not a LEAVE, there is at least one subscriber.